# Close the question with reason

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close

I don't know if the above title is the best suited to what I'm going to explain the problem. Here's the problem: How do we know which part of our question was not good to ask on the platform? Okay, let me be more specific. Take this example [Is mentalism real?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/29831/is-mentalism-real). This question I asked was closed. But I have a humble request to those who close the question that they should **highlight** (like with **red color**) the part of the question that was off-topic, duplicate, or any other thing, and yes with a **valid reason**. If you do so, the people who ask questions will not make the same mistake again, especially beginners.

Comment: "those who close the question [...] should highlight [....] the part of the question that was off-topic, duplicate, or any other thing" - questions aren't closed because *part* of them is off-topic, but because *the whole thing* is off-topic. If only part of it is off-topic, then the question can still be salvaged by editing out the off-topic parts. [1/2]

Comment: [2/2] I'm not familiar with Psychology.SE's scope, and can't say why your particular question was closed, but I would assume that that was the case here, hence why your question wasn't edited to try and salvage it. If you don't understand why your question is off-topic, and need more specific guidance about how to get it reopened, then you'll need to ask on [the Psychology-specific Meta site](https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/) rather than here.

Comment: People can post comments to explain why they closed a question. No need for adding complex red color highlights.

Comment: Then, at least one comment should be necessary before closing the question. Simply downvoting and closing the question does not give any clue to the asker as to why the question was closed, especially if the linked post doesn't make sense. Anyway, it seems I should not ask why the question was closed here. Instead, I should ask on the Psychology Stack Exchange website.

Comment: Your question on [psychology.se] might be a better fit for [skeptics.se]. Before posting a question on that community, review thoroughly their Asking question guidelines.

Answer (score 11):

What part of the close reason that was embedded in the post was difficult to parse out?

[image]

> This question is not framed in psychology or neuroscience. It is based on assumptions which are not made explicit, are not well-motivated (e.g., referenced), or are not held to be true within any of the research fields on-topic here. For more information, see [Why was my question closed as “not framed in psychology or neuroscience”](https://psychology.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2277/21)?.
>
> Closed yesterday.

In a bid to say that this could be a global, network-wide thing, every site has generic close reasons and specific close reasons, and in those close reasons, they provide a *lot* of explanation as to why the question was closed, along with resources to justify it.

If you have further questions about your *specific* question on that *specific* site, then you'll need to take it up on their Meta site.  But please do so only after you've read through everything on the linked question, otherwise you may not be very well received if it *appears* that you're just going to that Meta site to vent and fuss about why your question was closed without understanding the justifications.

Comment: Psychology site clearly mentioned that "non-expert questions are welcome". So, to clarify, I'm a non-expert in Psychology. I told the background what actually happened. If a non-expert person sees something that they don't see the fact as true, they search for Google, also like Wikipedia (which I did), but if they don't find the clear answer, where will they go? Of course, Stack Exchange websites, right? But their question is closed with a vague description. As in my example, my question was closed because "It is based on assumptions". But there are no assumptions involved in my question.

Comment: @LeviAckerman:  Did you follow the link provided at all? I think you'd get a lot further if you followed the link.

Comment: Yes, I followed the link provided. I also knew why my question was closed (seeing the comments in the linked question). But the assumption part was not at all a reason to close my question.

Comment: @LeviAckerman: You should take it up with the folks on Psychology Meta, not us.  All we can do is tell you what they said.  Only they can justify it.